# Passing input value to sibling through parent

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to pass input value from one child to another child using `setState`. It renders the first element, but not the second element in the first child...

```
class App extends Component { 
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
    }; 

    showTekst = () => {
        const inpValue = document.querySelector('.inpValue').value;
        this.setState({
            name: 'Bruce Wayne',
            namefromvalue: inpValue.value
        });
    } 

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="app">
                <Button showTekst={this.showTekst.bind(this)} />
                <Text name={this.state.name} namefromvalue={this.state.namefromvalue}/> 
                <Inputvalue /> 
            </div>
        );
    } 
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

class Inputvalue extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <input className="inpValue"></input>
        );
    }
}

class Text extends Component {
    render() {
        return (   
            <div>
                <h1>This is text..</h1>
                <h2>{this.props.namefromvalue}</h2>
                <p>{this.props.name}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you rendering `SecondChild`? You state in the title that it should be a sibling of `InputValue`, but it is not being rendered.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I changed the component names to be more clear. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show the text from the `Inputvalue` component in the `Text` component only when the `Button` component is clicked you can store the input value in the `App` instance and update the `App` state when the `Button` is clicked.

To do so, we define an `onChange` prop in the `Inputvalue` component so that every time the text in the input changes, the prop is called with the new value. With that prop we update the value in the `App` instance. This value will always be in sync with the input value.

Last, when the button is clicked we update the `App` state with the input value so that the `Text` component renders its value.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};

    // This variable will hold the input value.
    this.inputValue = "";
  }

  showTekst = () => {
    // Update with the current input value.
    this.setState({
      name: "Bruce Wayne",
      namefromvalue: this.inputValue
    });
  };

  onInputChange = value => {
    // Update the input value.
    this.inputValue = value;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <Button showTekst={this.showTekst.bind(this)} />
        <Text name={this.state.name} namefromvalue={this.state.namefromvalue} />
        <Inputvalue onChange={this.onInputChange} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

class Button extends Component {
  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.props.showTekst}>Show text</button>;
  }
}

class Inputvalue extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <input
        className="inpValue"
        onChange={ev => this.props.onChange(ev.target.value)}
      />
    );
  }
}

class Text extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>This is text..</h1>
        <h2>{this.props.namefromvalue}</h2>
        <p>{this.props.name}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```